# Call to function is ambiguous when irrelevant type defined as alias

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

After reading of a great article [*True Story: Efficient Packing*](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-22/true-story-efficient-packing) I tried to implement tuple by myself as exercise:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
struct tuple_leaf { T value; };

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
T & get(tuple_leaf< I, T > & leaf)
{ return leaf.value; }

template< typename Is, typename ...Ts >
struct tuple_base;

template< std::size_t ...Is, typename ...Ts >
struct tuple_base< std::index_sequence< Is... >, Ts... >
    : tuple_leaf< Is, Ts >...
{
    using tuple_base_t = tuple_base;
    template< typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t< (sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Args)) > >
    tuple_base(Args &&... args)
        : tuple_leaf< Is, Ts >{std::forward< Args >(args)}...
    { ; }
};

#if 0
template< typename ...Ts >
struct tuple
    : tuple_base< std::index_sequence_for< Ts... >, Ts... >
{
    using tuple_base_t = typename tuple::tuple_base_t;
    using tuple_base_t::tuple_base_t;
    using tuple_base_t::operator = ;
};
#else
// terse
template< typename ...Ts >
using tuple = tuple_base< std::index_sequence_for< Ts... >, Ts... >;
#endif

template< typename ...Args >
tuple< Args &&... >
forward_as_tuple(Args &&... args)
{ return {std::forward< Args >(args)...}; }

#include <tuple>

int
main()
{
    tuple< int > t(1);
    auto f = forward_as_tuple(t);
    (void)f;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62b71c523a326ae6)

After implementation of `forward_as_tuple` I decide to change definition of `tuple` type from *class template* to *alias template* of its base class template, because all I need from splitting into class `tuple` itself and its implementation class `tuple_base` is just `std::index_sequence_for` for variadic template type parameters pack — *alias template* is exactly suitable tool for this purpose. After doing that I get an error (`#if 0` case):

> error: call to 'forward_as_tuple' is ambiguous

It looks strange for me, because *alias template* does nothing and on the other hand `forward_as_tuple` called for type from the same namespace - I was hoping that ADL should work for the case above for sure.

How to explain the difference between `#if 1` and `#if 0` versions of code?

Comment: `std::index_sequence_for` becomes a type template argument of the type of the argument of a function call, so `std` is examined by ADL. BTW. You'll get the same error if you use `tuple< std::string >` directly

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Subtle moment. I always keep in mind that ADL is just for function argument types, but is also for template parameters.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `tuple_base< std::index_sequence_for< tuple_base< std::index_sequence_for< int >, int > >, tuple_base< std::index_sequence_for< int >, int > >` is the function argument. `std::index_sequence_for` is deep inside. I.e. it is not top template name. Does it matter?

Comment: what do you mean by *deep inside* ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki In type `A< B< int > >`: `B` is *inside*, but `A` - is top level name. I think `B` was hiding in some sense.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki does it mean, that I can't always use unqualified names, defined in my own namespace and injected by means of `using namespace ...;`, which have counterparts in `std::` namespace?

Comment: it will be ambiguous if the type of an argument or a type template argument of that argument's class template comes from a namespace declaring an equally viable candidate. you can disable ADL by using parenthesis, `(forward_as_tuple)(t);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Is it true, that in my library's code (defined in its own namespace) I should always use parenthesis for all the callings of functions from the same library. The error firstly catched in `tuple_cat` implementation.

Comment: why won't you use qualified names?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki In definition of `tuple_cat`, which placed in the same namespace as `forward_as_tuple` I thought it was normal to call later from former without any additional things like `()` around name. Now I warry about of all my code written before: what to do, if, say, C++17 introduce a function with name, that I define for free function and locally use it in my library for years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adl causes lookup in the type passed, and the template arguments of the type passed.

The tuple non-alias has its types and itself as places to look for ADL.

The tuple alias case has a `std::index_sequence` in its template argument list.  This causes `std::forward_as_tuple` to be considered, in addition to your `forward_as_tuple`.  They are equally good matches, and ambiguity occurs.

As @Piotr noted above in comments, `tuple<std::string>` exhibits this problem even in the non-alias case.